# PayPal After NVP Callback Shipping Doesn't Update

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I am trying to update the shipping cost when on the paypal checkout screen. I have followed the integration and looked up sample and I am never able to display a shipping cost other than what's been sent with *SetExpressCheckout*.

I know my callback is being called, but the shipping cost doesn't update.

This is my response. I have tried a static page too.

> METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=false&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=CAD&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Local+Pickup&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=Local+Pickup+-+0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=Regular+Parcel&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=Regular+Parcel+-+12.15&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=12.15&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=Xpresspost&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL2=Xpresspost+-+13.04&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=13.04&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false

Comment: I'm assuming you've confirmed the callback is getting hit with logs of some sort..??  Are you hitting a carrier API to generate the response string back to PayPal or are you just pulling from a database or something?  I ask because in my experience you have to be VERY quick with the callback API.  In theory it will wait 6 seconds (if you set that in the request) but in practice it doesn't seem to do that.  I've found that if I can't get my result back to PayPal within just a couple of seconds it won't use it, but will fall to defaults instead.

Comment: I have confirmed the callback is getting hit. I am using a 3rd party api to get the shipping options. But I have tried bypassing it and returning a static result with no difference.

Comment: The response format looks ok from what I can tell, so if you're passing that as a static result without any lookup at all, there's no reason it wouldn't be working unless your callback script isn't getting hit like you think it is.  Again, I've seen the callback act finicky, but only if it takes a few seconds (as opposed to almost instant) to return a result.

Comment: If you're absolutely sure that your callback script is getting hit (through logging) then you'll need to post a ticket to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) directly.  Attach your log proving your script was hit, and provide a sample of the response string you're sending back to PayPal.  They can help you get it turned on if it's somehow actually off on your account or something like that.